# Version control and git checkout/clone

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, github

I am using Bootstrap SASS. I learning git slowly. I want to be able to update files located in folders from this repo on git when they are updated, however I don't want to clone the entire repo, as I use a different file structure. As an example:

Bootstrap SASS holds the js files here:

```
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap
```

My local js files are here:

```
app/assets/javascripts/scripts
```

In my local directory I have additional scripts which I concat in with bootstrap .js files. My question is, How would I clone/update the files in a folder from the bootstrap SASS repo to the local repo without having conflict with the addition scripts inside my local repo and not having to clone the entire repo, just the files or better yet particular files.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you really aren't using the full bootstrap SASS repo but only specific files, it is best to version a script able to copy files from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass, using the raw address (https://raw.githubusercontent.com):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js
```

If that scripts copies files that are modified since the last copy, a git status in your repo will detect it and will allow you to add, commit and push.

If that script copies files that are unchanged since the last copy, the git status will report a clean repo.

Comment: This script you talk of, where can I learn how to build one? I am sorry, I just having a little trouble understanding...

Comment: @Esotericist that would be a simple script in the scripting language of your choice (simple shell if you are using Linux), with a collection of copy commands: `copy https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js a/path/in/your/git/repo`. Nothing complex really.

Comment: I see! thanks for your response! i will have a play around and see what I can come up with.